# Cordova + AngularJs routing not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

We are using Cordova/Phonegap with AngularJs and trying to use routing; the routing isn't working, it's not changing view, and is coming up with the below error in the console:

**Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on this server.**

Our routing controller is:

```
var app = angular
.module('myApp', [])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html'
    }).when('/HomeScreen/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/homeScreen.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
});
```

When we change `.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/HomeScreen/1'})` it works but then the anchors in index.html with the same `href` (/HomeScreen/1) don't work.

We have tried Html5 mode and hashbang mode with neither working.

We are using angularjs version 1.0.7.

Comment: If it's not too noisy, can you please include the contents of `index.html`?

Comment: Actually, does it work if you change your `/HomeScreen/:id` `templateUrl` to `'views/homeScreen.html'` (omit the `'app/'` portion)?

Comment: Wait, when '/' then it's your index.html?  If index.html is a partial, then what is the main page?  Post code sample on jsfiddle?

Comment: Was there ever a resolution to this? Blocking on the identical error...

Comment: Did u find any solution? I have the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is that the #/ is getting some of the browsers confused. This might help:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

This will use push state to do the navigation instead.